# POST in node.js fails

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, rest

I'm working on a Python API to handle REST calls to MongoDB. The API is based on [Kule](https://github.com/fatiherikli/kule) (and thus includes Bottle and PyMongo modules). The front-end is built using node.js. I have been developing and testing on localhost with the API, front-end, and MongoDB on different ports.

I have set up the API and have been trying to get CRUD requests to work. I can get these to work from a Python script as well as from Javascript running on Apache server. However, when I add the same code to the front-end, GET works, but POST fails with a 500 error.

This POST code works on the Apache server:

```
var myrequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
myrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (myrequest.readyState==4){
    if (myrequest.status==201){
      alert(myrequest.responseText);
    } else{
      alert("An error has occured making the request");
    }
  }
}
myrequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/items", true);
myrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
myrequest.send(JSON.stringify({'name' : 'Name', 'description' : 'Description'}));
```

When I add this to the front-end, I get the following traceback from Kule:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1625, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kule\kule.py", line 64, in post_list
    inserted = collection.insert(request.json)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 351, in insert
    docs = [self.__database._fix_incoming(doc, self) for doc in docs]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 07:53:40] "POST /scenarios HTTP/1.1" 500 50
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why does the Javascript break in node.js? I have GET working, but POST fails. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error.

```
myrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

"Content-type" should be "Content-Type" with an upercase "T".

Silly mistake. Left as a note to others.